# How do the files to upload get passed from Dropzone to the action URL?

Tags: php, jquery, forms, dropzone.js

I have a form built as a custom Typo3 (PHP) extension. Before attaching Dropzone, the form works correctly- if I fill out the information, upload a file, and submit the form, the correct actions take place (in this case, this means I receive an email with all the information & the uploaded file as an attachment).

If I follow the instructions in this article [Combine normal form with Dropzone](https://github.com/enyo/dropzone/wiki/Combine-normal-form-with-Dropzone), I can drag and drop files onto my forms, and the file previews are visible. When I click "Submit", I get a Typo3/PHP error:

```
   :saveUserFiles() must be of the type array, null given
```

This looks like a problem with the way Dropzone is passing the files to the back-end- is there any way for me to look at WHAT Dropzone is passing on submit?

Here's my Dropzone options, hardly changed from the suggestions at the FAQ page above:

```
 Dropzone.options.general = {
                paramName: "file", // The name that will be used to transfer the file

                autoProcessQueue: false,
                uploadMultiple: true,
                parallelUploads: 100,
                maxFiles: 100,
                addRemoveLinks: true,

                // The setting up of the dropzone
                init: function() {
                    var myDropzone = this;

                    // First change the button to actually tell Dropzone to process the queue.
                    this.element.querySelector("button[type=submit]").addEventListener("click", function(e) {
                        // Make sure that the form isn't actually being sent.
                        e.preventDefault();
                        e.stopPropagation();
                        myDropzone.processQueue();
                    });

                    // Listen to the sendingmultiple event. In this case, it's the sendingmultiple event instead
                    // of the sending event because uploadMultiple is set to true.
                    this.on("sendingmultiple", function() {
                        console.log("sending multiple");
                    });
                    this.on("successmultiple", function(files, response) {
                        console.log("success multiple");
                    });
                    this.on("errormultiple", function(files, response) {
                        console.log("error multiple");
                    });
                }
            };
```

--

**Update, in response to comment:**

The "normal upload" input looked like this:

```
<input type="file" name="tx_applicationformgeneral[form][files][]" />
```

I tried putting the name of the file input into the Dropzone options, like this:

```
paramName: "tx_applicationformgeneral[form][files][]",
```

But got the same error back.

Here's the whole form structure (simplified- it's a really long form):

```
 <form enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post" name="form" class="dropzone dz-clickable" id="general" action="index.php?id=328">


<fieldset>

    <legend>Some input</legend>


    <ul class="inline-textbox">
        <li>

    <input type="text" id="first_name" name="tx_applicationformgeneral[form][firstname]" value="" placeholder="Name *">
        </li>
        <li>

    </ul>
</fieldset>

<fieldset>

    <legend>File upload</legend>

    <div class="dropzone-previews">

    </div>

</fieldset>


<input class="button" type="submit" name="tx_applicationformgeneral[mySubmit]" value="Submit">

 </form>
```

---

**Update 2**

After looking at the POST data as suggested in comments, I can now report that what is happening is that when the form is that the "Dropzoned" form sends NO data for the file upload input. The "non-Dropzoned" form sends this chunk of data if the file upload is empty:

```
 ------WebKitFormBoundarySq0AkJrSAe1kmAOu
 Content-Disposition: form-data; name="tx_applicationformgeneral[form][files][]";      filename=""
 Content-Type: application/octet-stream
```

And this if there is a file:

```
 ------WebKitFormBoundaryrEmFA8jYcHY56WAB
 Content-Disposition: form-data; name="tx_applicationformgeneral[form][files][]";      filename="DSC01413_01.JPG"
 Content-Type: image/jpeg
```

There is nothing corresponding to this information in the POST data once I've initialised the form as a Dropzone.

Comment: So what does your “normal” form look like? How are the file input fields named in that? Does it correspond to `paramName: "file"` as you stated in the Dropzone options?

Comment: Well then as a next step, I’d compare the data send by the browser for a “normal” upload and one via Dropzone, via the browser’s developer tools – any significant differences in there, especially regarding the parameter names? You might also look at the received data server-side, f.e. a var_dump of the received POST data.

Comment: Appreciate the pointer to capture the POST data, very helpful. It turns out that the "Non-Dropzone" form includes an empty payload for the file-upload input name if there is no file, and a non-empty one if there is a file. The "Dropzoned" form never includes a payload for this input name. Is this the function of paramName in the Dropzone options?

Comment: http://www.dropzonejs.com/#toc_6 says about `paramName`, _“NOTE: If you have the option uploadMultiple set to true, then Dropzone will append [] to the name.”_ – so try using `paramName: "tx_applicationformgeneral[form][files]"`, without the empty pair of square brackets at the end.